# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT Retrofit Api call fails

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm creating an Android project for school. Now i want to recieve data from this API using retrofit: [Edamam](https://test-es.edamam.com/search). I keep getting the error shown in the title of this question.

Here are my classes:

Api.java

```
public interface Api {

final String BASE_URL = "API URL";
final String APP_ID = "SECRET ID";
final String APP_KEY = "SECRET KEY";

@GET("search")
Call<Hits> getHits(@Query("q") String keyword, @Query("app_id") String app_id, @Query("app_key") String app_key);}
```

HitsController.java

```
public class HitsController {

public void getHits(String keyword) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    Call<Hits> call = api.getHits(keyword, Api.APP_ID, Api.APP_KEY);

    //the enqueue is async
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Hits>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Hits> call, Response<Hits> response) {
            Hits hits = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + hits.getCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Hits> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: the call failed.");
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + call.request().url().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }

    });

}
```

}

JSON preview (Hits with one Hit):

```
{
"q": "chicken",
"from": 0,
"to": 10,
"params": {
    "sane": [],
    "q": [
        "chicken"
    ],
    "app_key": [
        "5b5829870f140360800ce3af3a6b6781"
    ],
    "app_id": [
        "0ddbef04"
    ]
},
"more": true,
"count": 190722,
"hits": [
    {
        "recipe": {
            "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_7bf4a371c6884d809682a72808da7dc2",
            "label": "Teriyaki Chicken",
            "image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/262/262b4353ca25074178ead2a07cdf7dc1.jpg",
            "source": "David Lebovitz",
            "url": "http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2012/12/chicken-teriyaki-recipe-japanese-farm-food/",
            "shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/teriyaki-chicken-7bf4a371c6884d809682a72808da7dc2/chicken",
            "yield": 6,
            "dietLabels": [
                "Low-Carb"
            ],
            "healthLabels": [
                "Sugar-Conscious",
                "Peanut-Free",
                "Tree-Nut-Free",
                "Alcohol-Free"
            ],
            "cautions": [],
            "ingredientLines": [
                "1/2 cup (125ml) mirin",
                "1/2 cup (125ml) soy sauce",
                "One 2-inch (5cm) piece of fresh ginger, peeled and grated",
                "2-pounds (900g) boneless chicken thighs (4-8 thighs, depending on size)"
            ],
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "text": "1/2 cup (125ml) mirin",
                    "weight": 122.99850757795392
                },
                {
                    "text": "1/2 cup (125ml) soy sauce",
                    "weight": 134.72774670265568
                },
                {
                    "text": "One 2-inch (5cm) piece of fresh ginger, peeled and grated",
                    "weight": 15
                },
                {
                    "text": "2-pounds (900g) boneless chicken thighs (4-8 thighs, depending on size)",
                    "weight": 907.18474
                }
            ],
            "calories": 2253.101981306866,
            "totalWeight": 1179.9109942806097,
            "totalTime": 0,
            "totalNutrients": {
                "ENERC_KCAL": {
                    "label": "Energy",
                    "quantity": 2253.101981306866,
                    "unit": "kcal"
                },
                "FAT": {
                    "label": "Fat",
                    "quantity": 151.56383347020517,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "FASAT": {
                    "label": "Saturated",
                    "quantity": 41.169838892692944,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "FATRN": {
                    "label": "Trans",
                    "quantity": 0.7711070290000002,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "FAMS": {
                    "label": "Monounsaturated",
                    "quantity": 63.10028137309835,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "FAPU": {
                    "label": "Polyunsaturated",
                    "quantity": 31.82952890962799,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "CHOCDF": {
                    "label": "Carbs",
                    "quantity": 17.72546514133862,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "FIBTG": {
                    "label": "Fiber",
                    "quantity": 1.3778219736212456,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "SUGAR": {
                    "label": "Sugars",
                    "quantity": 0.7939109868106228,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "PROCNT": {
                    "label": "Protein",
                    "quantity": 161.72175016748596,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                "CHOLE": {
                    "label": "Cholesterol",
                    "quantity": 889.0410452000001,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "NA": {
                    "label": "Sodium",
                    "quantity": 8139.824735928436,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "CA": {
                    "label": "Calcium",
                    "quantity": 116.51301359077408,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "MG": {
                    "label": "Magnesium",
                    "quantity": 276.82169621464243,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "K": {
                    "label": "Potassium",
                    "quantity": 2529.722194651041,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "FE": {
                    "label": "Iron",
                    "quantity": 8.335407066766463,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "ZN": {
                    "label": "Zinc",
                    "quantity": 12.950414243828696,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "P": {
                    "label": "Phosphorus",
                    "quantity": 1660.4080117810859,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "VITA_RAE": {
                    "label": "Vitamin A",
                    "quantity": 208.65249020000002,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                "VITC": {
                    "label": "Vitamin C",
                    "quantity": 0.75,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "THIA": {
                    "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
                    "quantity": 0.7104550166118764,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "RIBF": {
                    "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
                    "quantity": 1.542818655059382,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "NIA": {
                    "label": "Niacin (B3)",
                    "quantity": 45.028415542590324,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "VITB6A": {
                    "label": "Vitamin B6",
                    "quantity": 3.3713281129199304,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "FOLDFE": {
                    "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
                    "quantity": 47.7274267383718,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                "FOLFD": {
                    "label": "Folate (food)",
                    "quantity": 47.7274267383718,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                "VITB12": {
                    "label": "Vitamin B12",
                    "quantity": 5.6245453880000005,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                "VITD": {
                    "label": "Vitamin D",
                    "quantity": 0.9071847400000002,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                "TOCPHA": {
                    "label": "Vitamin E",
                    "quantity": 1.944087954,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                "VITK1": {
                    "label": "Vitamin K",
                    "quantity": 19.065879540000005,
                    "unit": "µg"
                }
            },
            "totalDaily": {
                "ENERC_KCAL": {
                    "label": "Energy",
                    "quantity": 112.6550990653433,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "FAT": {
                    "label": "Fat",
                    "quantity": 233.17512841570027,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "FASAT": {
                    "label": "Saturated",
                    "quantity": 205.8491944634647,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "CHOCDF": {
                    "label": "Carbs",
                    "quantity": 5.908488380446207,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "FIBTG": {
                    "label": "Fiber",
                    "quantity": 5.511287894484982,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "PROCNT": {
                    "label": "Protein",
                    "quantity": 323.44350033497193,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "CHOLE": {
                    "label": "Cholesterol",
                    "quantity": 296.3470150666667,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "NA": {
                    "label": "Sodium",
                    "quantity": 339.1593639970182,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "CA": {
                    "label": "Calcium",
                    "quantity": 11.651301359077408,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "MG": {
                    "label": "Magnesium",
                    "quantity": 65.90992767015297,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "K": {
                    "label": "Potassium",
                    "quantity": 53.823876481937035,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "FE": {
                    "label": "Iron",
                    "quantity": 46.307817037591455,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "ZN": {
                    "label": "Zinc",
                    "quantity": 117.73103858026087,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "P": {
                    "label": "Phosphorus",
                    "quantity": 237.20114454015513,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITA_RAE": {
                    "label": "Vitamin A",
                    "quantity": 23.183610022222226,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITC": {
                    "label": "Vitamin C",
                    "quantity": 0.8333333333333334,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "THIA": {
                    "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
                    "quantity": 59.204584717656374,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "RIBF": {
                    "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
                    "quantity": 118.67835808149093,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "NIA": {
                    "label": "Niacin (B3)",
                    "quantity": 281.4275971411895,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITB6A": {
                    "label": "Vitamin B6",
                    "quantity": 259.33293176307154,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "FOLDFE": {
                    "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
                    "quantity": 11.93185668459295,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITB12": {
                    "label": "Vitamin B12",
                    "quantity": 234.35605783333335,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITD": {
                    "label": "Vitamin D",
                    "quantity": 6.047898266666667,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "TOCPHA": {
                    "label": "Vitamin E",
                    "quantity": 12.96058636,
                    "unit": "%"
                },
                "VITK1": {
                    "label": "Vitamin K",
                    "quantity": 15.888232950000004,
                    "unit": "%"
                }
            },
            "digest": [
                {
                    "label": "Fat",
                    "tag": "FAT",
                    "schemaOrgTag": "fatContent",
                    "total": 151.56383347020517,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 233.17512841570027,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "sub": [
                        {
                            "label": "Saturated",
                            "tag": "FASAT",
                            "schemaOrgTag": "saturatedFatContent",
                            "total": 41.169838892692944,
                            "hasRDI": true,
                            "daily": 205.8491944634647,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Trans",
                            "tag": "FATRN",
                            "schemaOrgTag": "transFatContent",
                            "total": 0.7711070290000002,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Monounsaturated",
                            "tag": "FAMS",
                            "schemaOrgTag": null,
                            "total": 63.10028137309835,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Polyunsaturated",
                            "tag": "FAPU",
                            "schemaOrgTag": null,
                            "total": 31.82952890962799,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Carbs",
                    "tag": "CHOCDF",
                    "schemaOrgTag": "carbohydrateContent",
                    "total": 17.72546514133862,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 5.908488380446207,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "sub": [
                        {
                            "label": "Carbs (net)",
                            "tag": "CHOCDF.net",
                            "schemaOrgTag": null,
                            "total": 16.347643167717376,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Fiber",
                            "tag": "FIBTG",
                            "schemaOrgTag": "fiberContent",
                            "total": 1.3778219736212456,
                            "hasRDI": true,
                            "daily": 5.511287894484982,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Sugars",
                            "tag": "SUGAR",
                            "schemaOrgTag": "sugarContent",
                            "total": 0.7939109868106228,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Sugars, added",
                            "tag": "SUGAR.added",
                            "schemaOrgTag": null,
                            "total": 0,
                            "hasRDI": false,
                            "daily": 0,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Protein",
                    "tag": "PROCNT",
                    "schemaOrgTag": "proteinContent",
                    "total": 161.72175016748596,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 323.44350033497193,
                    "unit": "g"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Cholesterol",
                    "tag": "CHOLE",
                    "schemaOrgTag": "cholesterolContent",
                    "total": 889.0410452000001,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 296.3470150666667,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Sodium",
                    "tag": "NA",
                    "schemaOrgTag": "sodiumContent",
                    "total": 8139.824735928436,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 339.1593639970182,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Calcium",
                    "tag": "CA",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 116.51301359077408,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 11.651301359077408,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Magnesium",
                    "tag": "MG",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 276.82169621464243,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 65.90992767015297,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Potassium",
                    "tag": "K",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 2529.722194651041,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 53.823876481937035,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Iron",
                    "tag": "FE",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 8.335407066766463,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 46.307817037591455,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Zinc",
                    "tag": "ZN",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 12.950414243828696,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 117.73103858026087,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Phosphorus",
                    "tag": "P",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 1660.4080117810859,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 237.20114454015513,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin A",
                    "tag": "VITA_RAE",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 208.65249020000002,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 23.183610022222226,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin C",
                    "tag": "VITC",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 0.75,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 0.8333333333333334,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
                    "tag": "THIA",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 0.7104550166118764,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 59.204584717656374,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
                    "tag": "RIBF",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 1.542818655059382,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 118.67835808149093,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Niacin (B3)",
                    "tag": "NIA",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 45.028415542590324,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 281.4275971411895,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin B6",
                    "tag": "VITB6A",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 3.3713281129199304,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 259.33293176307154,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
                    "tag": "FOLDFE",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 47.7274267383718,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 11.93185668459295,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Folate (food)",
                    "tag": "FOLFD",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 47.7274267383718,
                    "hasRDI": false,
                    "daily": 0,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Folic acid",
                    "tag": "FOLAC",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 0,
                    "hasRDI": false,
                    "daily": 0,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin B12",
                    "tag": "VITB12",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 5.6245453880000005,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 234.35605783333335,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin D",
                    "tag": "VITD",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 0.9071847400000002,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 6.047898266666667,
                    "unit": "µg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin E",
                    "tag": "TOCPHA",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 1.944087954,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 12.96058636,
                    "unit": "mg"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Vitamin K",
                    "tag": "VITK1",
                    "schemaOrgTag": null,
                    "total": 19.065879540000005,
                    "hasRDI": true,
                    "daily": 15.888232950000004,
                    "unit": "µg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "bookmarked": false,
        "bought": false
    },
```

As you can see a lot of model classes are needed:
[preview classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFVN2.png)

I am clueless, I went through every other post but can't seem to find an answer for my problem...

I hope that someone is able to help me!
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: POSTED THE HITS CLASS

```
public class Hits {

private String q;
private int from;
private int to;
private String[][] params;
private int count;
private boolean more;
private Hit[] hits;

public Hits(String q, int from, int to, String[][] params, int count, boolean more, Hit[] hits) {
    this.q = q;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.params = params;
    this.count = count;
    this.more = more;
    this.hits = hits;
}

public String getQ() {
    return q;
}

public int getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public int getTo() {
    return to;
}

public String[][] getParams() {
    return params;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public boolean isMore() {
    return more;
}

public Hit[] getHits() {
    return hits;
}
```

}

Comment: the json does not match the model classes which you have not shown.

Comment: Post your Hits class. Basically, you need to create a hierarchy in your models that matches the hierarchy in your JSON.

Comment: Posted the Hits class, I followed https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api for the setup of all the classes.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the stacktrace to the post?

Comment: Your json is invalid. Post an actual complete server response

Comment: @saiedmomen the full json response was too long to post, stack overflow wouldn’t let me. I was about to check out the site you commented, but your post dissapeared.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry but I wasn't sure it that was your exact problem

Comment: here's the site though http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @cricket, Will do that, but my gf ordered me to sleep now.. I’ll post it in the morning

Comment: You could delete all the items in array except one

Comment: Thanks! I’ll let you know if my models were wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to get configure retrofit to get only a List of Hits, that is `List<Hits>`
but its much easier if you created a Java bean which will contain the list of Hits inside, just like the Json response its a object that has a array inside.

For example you have a Example class which has a `List<Hits> hits` inside

```
public class Example{

@SerializedName("hits")
private List<Hits> hits;
// optionally you can add the other fields also (not mandatory)

// set getters and setters here
```

and then you need to modify your Retrofit interface to return a Example object which will contain the Hits

```
@GET("search")
Call<Example> getExample(@Query("q") String keyword, @Query("app_id") String app_id, @Query("app_key") String app_key);}
```

and the implementation also

```
Call<Example> call = api.getHits(keyword, Api.APP_ID, Api.APP_KEY);

//the enqueue is async
call.enqueue(new Callback<Hits>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
        Hits hits = response.body();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.getHits().size());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sorry if I'm not totally understanding you but the JSON only has one HITS with an array of HIT in it.

Comment: First you need to have some basics of Json.
The Json that you provided has the following fields
  ` "q",` 
  ` "from",`
   `"to",`
   `"params":{  },`
   `"more",`
   `"count",`
   `"hits":[  ]`
When you see { at the end it means that its a Object so you have to create a java object, and when you see [ you will need to create a java Array of that object for example here a ListArray of Hits.java
So create the classes as I have in the following link [link](https://gist.github.com/naimJus/419aa95f8ea6b9f69705a649f900da63)
and modify the retrofit as I explained earlier.

Comment: Got it working, model classes were not right. Thanks though.

Comment: The answer that helped me got removed.